# Transformer PyTorch Error- ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I am having issues getting my model to run. I am not sure which model to use in the translate_sentence function, I have tried model.transformer, model.encoder_de, etc. It is based off of the Transformer class and the forward() function I believe but I am getting a type error. These are the directions:

1. As in the forward(self, src, tgt) function of the
   TransformerModel class, you need to create the appropriate
   mask and encode the source sentence (just once).
2. You also need to create the appropriate mask and encode the
   output sentence for sequential predictions. Unlike the source,
   for every iteration, you need to re-encode the previous output and
   pass both the source sentence and previous output into the
   Transformer.

```
from torch.nn import Transformer
class TransformerModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, ntoken_in, ntoken_out, ninp, nhead, npf_dim, nlayers, src_pad_idx, trg_pad_idx, dropout=0.5):
        super(TransformerModel, self).__init__()

        # --------------- param -----------------
        # ntoken_in: the idx of the input word after tokenization 
        # ntoken_out: the idx of the input word w.r.t. the tokenization 
        # ninp: the number of expected features in the encoder/decoder inputs 
        # nhead: the number of multiAttention heads 
        # npf_dim: the dimension of the feedforward layer 
        # src_pad_idx: the token for padding in source language
        # trg_pad_idx: the token for padding in target language 
        # ----------------------------------------

        self.model_type = 'Transformer'
        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(ninp, dropout)
        self.transformer = Transformer(d_model=ninp, nhead=nhead, num_encoder_layers=nlayers, num_decoder_layers=nlayers,
                                       dim_feedforward=npf_dim, dropout=dropout, activation='relu')
      
        self.encoder_en = nn.Embedding(ntoken_in, ninp)  # tok_embedding for input 
        self.encoder_de = nn.Embedding(ntoken_out, ninp) # tok_embedding for output 
        self.ninp = ninp
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(ninp, ntoken_out)

        self.src_pad_idx = src_pad_idx
        self.tgt_pad_idx = trg_pad_idx

        self.init_weights()

    def _generate_src_key_mask(self, src):
        # for key_padding_mask in transformer
        # the positions with the value of True will be ignored while the position
        # with the value of False will be unchanged. We mask all padding words. 
        # The output dim is b*s
        src_mask = (src == self.src_pad_idx)
        return src_mask.T

    def _generate_tgt_mask(self, tgt, sz):
        # Beside key_padding_mask in transformer, the output or teacher input 
        # should be masked sequentially to prevent the model get any information 
        # from the future words it is going to predict 
        tgt_key_mask = tgt == self.tgt_pad_idx

        # We provide FloatTensor attn_mask. It will be added to the attention weight.
        mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
        attn_mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0)).to(tgt.device)
        return attn_mask, tgt_key_mask.T

    def init_weights(self):
        initrange = 0.1
        self.encoder_en.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.encoder_de.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
        self.decoder.bias.data.zero_()
        self.decoder.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)

    def forward(self, src, tgt):
        # src
        src_key_mask = self._generate_src_key_mask(src)
        src = self.encoder_en(src) * math.sqrt(self.ninp)  # use a learned encoder put stoi index to a feature space s*b --> s*b*e
        src = self.pos_encoder(src)  # add the pos feature toward feature space

        # tgt
        tgt_mask, tgt_key_mask = self._generate_tgt_mask(tgt, tgt.size(0))
        tgt = self.encoder_de(tgt) * math.sqrt(self.ninp) 
        tgt = self.pos_encoder(tgt)

        output = self.transformer(src, tgt, tgt_mask=tgt_mask, 
                                  src_key_padding_mask = src_key_mask, 
                                  tgt_key_padding_mask = tgt_key_mask)
        output = self.decoder(output)
        return output

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    # The positional encoding as described in the paper 
    # https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:x.size(0), :]
        return self.dropout(x)

# Here we intialize our model
INPUT_DIM = len(SRC.vocab)
OUTPUT_DIM = len(TRG.vocab)
print(INPUT_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)

HID_DIM = 256
N_LAYERS = 3
N_HEADS = 8
N_PF_DIM = 512
DROPOUT = 0.1

SRC_PAD_IDX = SRC.vocab.stoi[SRC.pad_token]
TRG_PAD_IDX = TRG.vocab.stoi[TRG.pad_token]

model =TransformerModel(ntoken_in = INPUT_DIM, ntoken_out=OUTPUT_DIM, ninp=HID_DIM, 
                        nhead=N_HEADS, npf_dim=N_PF_DIM, nlayers=N_LAYERS,
                        src_pad_idx=SRC_PAD_IDX, trg_pad_idx=TRG_PAD_IDX, dropout=DROPOUT).to(device)

def count_parameters(model: nn.Module):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

print(f'The model has {count_parameters(model):,} trainable parameters')

def initialize_weights(m):
    if hasattr(m, 'weight') and m.weight.dim() > 1:
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight.data)

model.apply(initialize_weights)


----------
def translate_sentence(sentence, src_field, trg_field, model, device, max_len = 50):

    model.eval()
        
    if isinstance(sentence, str):
        nlp = spacy.load('de')
        tokens = [token.text.lower() for token in nlp(sentence)]
    else:
        tokens = [token.lower() for token in sentence]

    #tokens = [src_field.init_token] + tokens + [src_field.eos_token]  
    src_indexes = [src_field.vocab.stoi[token] for token in tokens]
    src_tensor = torch.LongTensor(src_indexes).unsqueeze(1).to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        #model.?
        hidden, cell = model.encoder_en(src_tensor)

    # create a list to hold the output sentence, initialized with an <sos> token   
    
    trg_indexes = [trg_field.vocab.stoi[trg_field.init_token]]
    
    for i in range(max_len):

        trg_tensor = torch.LongTensor(trg_indexes).unsqueeze(1).to(device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            #model.?
            output, hidden, cell = model.encoder_de(trg_tensor, hidden, cell)
            
        pred_token = output.argmax(1).item()
        
        trg_indexes.append(pred_token)

        if pred_token == trg_field.vocab.stoi[trg_field.eos_token]:
            break
    
    trg_tokens = [trg_field.vocab.itos[i] for i in trg_indexes]
    
    return trg_tokens[1:]


----------
#getting error here

example_idx = 18

src = vars(train_data.examples[example_idx])['src']
trg = vars(train_data.examples[example_idx])['trg']

print(f'src = {src}')
print(f'trg = {trg}')

translation = translate_sentence(src, TRG, SRC, model, device)

print(f'predicted trg = {translation}')
```

Comment: If you check the `forward()` call of the `TransformerModel`, it expects `src` and `tgt` as arguments. But somewhere in your code, you may be passing only the first argument i.e. `src`.

Comment: i am not sure where to pass tgt, would it be in training?

Comment: From your posted code, I'm not able to find out where exactly you call the forward method of `TransformerModel`. I could see you're only calling the `model.transformer`'s forward method. Can you update the post by including the stack trace?

Comment: I updated the post with the directions. The changes have to be made in the translate sentence function

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example so that I could reproduce the error and check locally?